Is $1/F$ Schwartz if $F$ is "reverse Schwartz"?
Let's call a positive function $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ "reverse Schwartz" if $F$ is smooth and
$$\forall n \forall k,\quad\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{|x|^n}{|\partial_x^k F(x)|}=0\quad .$$
In other words, $F$ and all of its derivatives grow faster than polynomially for $|x|\to\infty$. Notice that, unlike $F$, $\partial_x^kF$ might have zeroes, but the condition only involves the limit for $x\to\infty$.
Question: if $F$ is reverse Schwartz, then does $1/F$ belong to the Schwartz class?
Remark: for the (usual) $n=0,\;k=1$ estimate to hold for $1/F$, it's sufficient that $|F'|\ll F^2$. So, for example, is there a reverse Schwartz that doesn't satisfy the estimate $|F'|\ll F^2$?

Motivation: I thought that functions such as
$$g(x)=\frac{1}{\cosh(x)}$$
should "obviously" be in the Schwartz class. But, when I tried to prove it, I found myself proving identities such as
$$\partial_x^k (R(e^x))=[(t\partial_t)^kR(t)]|_{t=e^x}$$
where $R=P/Q$ is a rational function, and trying to have some control on the degrees of numerator and denominator of the result in function of the degrees of $P$ and $Q$. Surely there must be some more obvious way to prove that $g(x)$ is Schwartz, right?
In two variables, the "obviously Schwartz-looking" function
$$g(x,y)=\frac{1}{\cosh(x)+\cosh(y)}$$
is $R(e^x,e^y)$ where
$$R(u,v)=\frac{uv}{v(u^2+1)+u(v^2+1)}.$$
Computing derivatives leads to
$$\partial_x^k\partial_y^\ell(R(e^x,e^y))=[(u\partial_u)^k(v\partial_v)^\ell R(u,v)]|_{u=e^x,\;v=e^y}.$$
And then I think one would have to consider total degree, and/or degrees in $u$ and in $v$, of numerator and denominator (the latter is not even a homogeneous polynomial).
Is this the way? Feels needlessly complicated.

perhaps consider a Gronwall's type approach to see if $|F'| \sim F^2$. Then scale up your argument for arbitrary $k$. My feeling is that it is true.
